# Unable to query MS Access database: "Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression"

Tags: c#

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox2.Text != "" & listBox1.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
            string q = "update info set name='" + textBox2.Text.ToString() + "' where id " + listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
            dosomething(q);
            textBox2.Text = "";


        }
    }
private void dosomething(String q)
    {
        try {
            cn.Open();
            cmd.CommandText = q;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cn.Close();
            loaddata();

        }
```

Whenever I try to update a data from MS Access using my program I get this error:
[image]

Is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: **warning** you are introducing sql injection attacks!

Answer (score 1):

You need an operator between `id " + listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();`. So:

```
id = " + listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

or whatever operator you want to use like >, >=,  etc...

Also you have:

```
string q = "update info set name='" +
```

but it needs to be:

```
string q = "update info set name ='" +
```

notice I added a space between name and the = sign.